# What is the meaning of かまして here?

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence I stumbled upon in the novel All You Need Is Kill

> まあ、アレだ。作戦なんてテキトーかましてりゃいいんだ

So what does かます means here? because the closest meaning I found has to do with delivering an attack or a verbal assault

Comment: Either 言う or する and I think it is the latter in this context.

Answer (score 3):

かます is not a verb with a specific meaning, but rather a verb that is used intstead of やる/言う/放つ/etc and makes the sentence sound slangy, rough or dirty. It's typically used with a bold/offensive action and carries a nuance similar to "blow/bust", although these words may not be applicable in your case. Here, テキトーかます is just a dirty version of テキトーにやる or テキトーに扱う.